# How do I call an arrays methods from the JSP page in JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I stumbled upon servlets and I just love them compared to scriptlets since they perfectly divide logic and view. But I'm having trouble calling instance methods in my JSP page.

I have the following JSP page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:forEach items="${stringarray}">
${stringarray}
<br/>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following Servlet:

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Servlet
 */
@WebServlet("/Servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet 
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public Servlet() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {   
        String[] strarray = new String[5];

        strarray[0] = "zero";
        strarray[1] = "one";
        strarray[2] = "two";
        strarray[3] = "three";
        strarray[4] = "four";

        request.setAttribute("stringarray", strarray);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

**Why can't I call the arrays methods with the dot separator in my JSP page?!**

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the following:

```
<c:forEach var="stringElement" items="${stringarray}">
  ${stringElement} 
  <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

The `c:forEach` tag loops over each element in the `${stringarray}`, but to access each item, you have to define a variable. See also the [TLD docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html)

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you.
What about calling the arrays methods?

Comment: Which `arrays` method are you referring to?

Comment: Fx. "${stringarray.toString}" - How do I accomplish that?

Comment: @Alex you need to write your own custom tag for that

Comment: @Alex, why would you want to call the `toString()` method of a String array? It would display something like `[Ljava.lang.String;@1372a1a`

Comment: The WHY is not important - It's the HOW that's important :)

Comment: The WHY is always important, because if something isn't straightforward, there's probably a good reason for it or is an alternative way that's much more straightforward...